# Concatenate on two strings, remove duplicates

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following data:

```
data = data.frame(
  name=c("bob", "bob", "mary", "mary", "mary"),
  colour=c("blue", "blue", "blue", "green", "green"),
  number=c(1,1,1,2,3))

data

  name colour number
1  bob   blue      1
2  bob   blue      1
3 mary   blue      1
4 mary  green      2
5 mary  green      3
```

How can I concatenate the above on two columns, removing any repeated strings?
I have tried:

```
data <- data %>% group_by(`name`) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(paste(na.omit(.), collapse = ", ")))
```

But get the following which is incorrect:

```
  name             colour  number
1  bob         blue, blue    1, 1
2 mary blue, green, green 1, 2, 3
```

Expected output:

```
 name      colour number
1  bob        blue      1
2 mary blue, green  1,2,3
```

Comment: use `unique(na.omit(.)` in the `paste

Comment: Try `data %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise_all(funs(toString(unique(na.omit(.)))))`

Comment: What is `na.omit(.)` supposed to do?

Comment: Good question zx8754. I copied this code from a real-world problem I'm having which has NAs. I needed to strip them out. 

@Sotos this works perfectly, thank you. You should submit this as an answer.

Comment: @Simon no need. I found one which already has an answer and used that to dupe it.

Comment: Searched for a while on Google and SO - must have missed this one.

Answer (score 0):

A data.table oneliner..

**sample data**

```
library(data.table)
DT <-fread("
  name colour number
            bob   blue      1
            bob   blue      1
           mary   blue      1
           mary  green      2
           mary  green      3")
```

**code**

```
cols <- c("colour", "number")
DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) { paste0( unique(x), collapse = ",") }), 
   by = ,(name), .SDcols = cols][]
```

**output**

```
#    name     colour number
# 1:  bob       blue      1
# 2: mary blue,green  1,2,3
```

Comment: Yes but you overfit it in the example. What happens with 150 columns? It's better to use `...lapply(.SD, ...)`

Comment: @Sotos. you are right I updated the answer

Comment: You don't need to specify columns If you do it for all the columns. Otherwise you did not do anything. You will still have to specify 150 names in your `cols` vector. In this case `DT[, lapply(.SD, fun), by = name]` would suffice